# Menu with delayed sub Menu view in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface, ecmascript-6, menu

I'm trying to implement Menu with similar behavior to this one https://www.ocado.com/browse/fresh-20002

namely with delayed sub cats view on hover and delayed sub cat blur on Mouse Leave
For now i made something like this for removing subcat -> onMouseLeave

```
removeChildren() {
setTimeout(
  function() {
    this.setState({ selected: [] });
  }.bind(this),
  700
);
```

}

and like this for showing subCats ->onMouseEnter

```
getChildren(category) {
let { selected } = this.state;
selected = [].concat(category);
setTimeout(
  function() {
    this.setState({ selected });
  }.bind(this),
  700
);
```

}

But it causing problem - a blinking menu when I start to moving faster around menu in this particular Ocado menu it just waiting some time and show/remove subcat, but it's not changing when i moving too fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is delayed handling of the event. When the user moves the mouse around very fast and fires a series of `MouseLeave`/`MouseEnter` events, your app should delay the handling of updating `state`, i.e. trigger UI updates, until the mouse stops for, say 700ms (as in your code). Only then the last `setState` function should be executed and the UI should reflect the last registered event.

You can create a new property in your React component called `timer`:

```
timer = null;
```

Take your `getChildren` function as an example. In the `getChildren` function that gets called when a `MouseEnter` event occurs:

```
getChildren(category) {
    let { selected } = this.state;
    selected = [].concat(category);
   // Clear out the current stored event.
    clearTimeout(this.timer)
    // Store this event in `this.timer` and if this is the last one fired in 700ms, the `setState` function will execute and UI will update.
    this.timer = setTimeout(function(){
        this.setState({ selected });
    }.bind(this), 700);
}
```

`MouseLeave` and the `removeChildren` function is very similar to the above.